# Euler angle flips when close to zero degree

Tags: computer-vision, eigen, euler-angles

I am using `quaternion` in Eigens to calculate `ZYX` euler angles by:

```
quaternion.toRotationMatrix().eulerAngles(2, 1, 0);
```

But I found the values can occasionally flip between a very small number and a number very close to `PI`. I roughly understand why this happens, and the range of euler angle `beta` could be [0, π] or [−π/2, π/2]. But I couldn't find any way to use the second range in Eigen.

Is there a way in `Eigen` to do that conversion?

Answer (score 1):

To quote the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Geometry__Module.html#ga17994d2e81b723295f5bc3b1f862ed3b), the range is given:

> The returned angles are in the ranges [0:pi]x[-pi:pi]x[-pi:pi].

Comment: I noticed that too, how can i convert it back to the other range? i did some google search and could not find an example code for doing that

Comment: Have a look at this "unsupported" module: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/classEigen_1_1EulerAngles.html, it allows for fully customizable conversions.